# how to build a video chat with WebRTC?

Tags: webrtc, videochat

I want to create a video chat with WebRTC, but i have no idea about this. I need my own WebRTC server to establish a video call from a  PC browser to another browser on PC or on android device, how should I do?

Comment: Without idea it'll be hard, right. Firstly check existing solutions, for example: https://github.com/sourcey/symple-webrtc-video-chat-demo

Comment: Own `WebRTC` implementation is pretty much doable. Just go through the samples on git hub  .[Here is one](https://github.com/njovy/AppRTCDemo) and [Here is a simple stepwise sample](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48849736/4168607).

Comment: I think you have to look into this article if you still needed it. [Android_Realtime_Communication_Using_WebRTC](https://github.com/mail2chromium/Android_Realtime_Communication_Using_WebRTC)

Answer (score -3):

Luckily we live in 2018 where most of the stuff already implemented. There are bunch of WebRTC Video Chat providers that provide API, SDK and docs for integration.

I used [ConnectyCube](https://connectycube.com/) in many of my applications. They provide WebRTC Video Calling functionality for iOS, Android and Web(JS).

- iOS WebRTC (video chat) guide https://developers.connectycube.com/ios/videocalling
- Android WebRTC (video chat) guide https://developers.connectycube.com/android/videocalling
- Javascript WebRTC (video chat) guide https://developers.connectycube.com/js/videocalling

WebRTC features supported:

- 1-1 video chat
- Group video chat
- WebRTC based
- VP8/H264 video codecs supported
- Mute/Unmute audio/video stream
- Switch video input devices (cameras)
- Video recording

The whole list of [supported features](https://connectycube.com/features/)

Highly recommend to try something like this and do not waste time on implementing everything from scratch by yourself.

Comment: This seems more like a Marketing blog not an answer to question.